# how to open specific fragment in onclick

Tags: java, android

i have 3 fragments inside an activity, it's a swipe menu with tabs viewpager

how to get into second fragment from another activity ?

what i mean by second fragment is when iam using this standart intent

```
                    Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(),Form_Mhs_04.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

it went to first intent (case 0)

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position){
            case 0 :
                fragment = new form_mhs_04_fragment1();
                break;
            case 1 :
                fragment = new form_mhs_04_fragment2();
                break;
            case 2 :
                fragment = new form_mhs_04_fragment3();
        }
        return fragment;
    }
```

Comment: Simple use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set 2nd fragment in `TabLayout` in this way. You have to pass the `position` that you want to select using `intent`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Form_Mhs_04.class);
i.putExtra("TAB_POSITION", 2);
startActivity(i);
```

Then inside your `Form_Mhs_04` activity get this position from intent and set `TabLayout` selected tab based on that.

```
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("TAB_POSITION", 0);

TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
if(tab != null)
    tab.select();
```